# Will READ UNCOMMITTED improve performance of write operations as well?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand I can enable READ UNCOMMITTED for certain queries if I don't care about update information and it will improve the performance of read queries. Will it also improve the performance of write operations which are running in parallel under load?

Comment: If you also have significant write operations, you probably shouldn't enable read committed, whether or not it helps.

Comment: I think you mean READ UNCOMMITTED??? But I am not sure what you are actually asking here.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. Transaction isolation levels have their guarantees. Read those guarantees, understand those guarantees, pick the appropriate level given your requirements. There's no "switch to X isolation to improve performance", this is a very complicated matter. If possible, get an experienced DBA to consider this - messing with transaction isolation is a great way to make everything horribly slow, or horribly broken.

Comment: @SeanLange and there's a chance that RCSI was actually meant.

Comment: @IvanStarostin that is a definite possibility. :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is like an Oxymoron. When one chooses a transaction isolation level to be READ COMMITTED - this basically means that "Any READ operation return values that are hardened as part of a completed transaction".

When a Write operation is being run in parallel (on the same data subset), these are actually prevented from writing by locks until a READ COMMITTED transaction completes. This is to ensure that there is consistency.

So basically, a Write operation (on the same data subset) cannot be executed until a READ query completes retrieving all the data.

If you really want to achieve a greater WRITE performance, you would have to go with READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level.

Comment: I'm really sorry. Typo in my question. I actually wanted to ask "Will READ UNCOMMITTED improve the performance of write operations as well?. Correcting the question.

Comment: Yes, it should. Basically, that eliminates an exclusive lock being placed. This will allow writes to go through and ultimately improve performance.